# MongoDb Aggregate group and sort applications

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

There are documents with structure:

```
{"appId":<id>,"time":<number>}
```

For the example let we assume we have:

```
{"appId":"A","time":1}
{"appId":"A","time":3}
{"appId":"A","time":5}
{"appId":"B","time":1}
{"appId":"B","time":2}
{"appId":"B","time":4}
{"appId":"B","time":6}
```

Is it possible to group the documents by appId, each group to be sorted by time, and all results to be shown from the latest time for the group like:

```
{"appId":"B","time":6}
{"appId":"B","time":4}
{"appId":"B","time":2}
{"appId":"B","time":1}

{"appId":"A","time":5}
{"appId":"A","time":3}
{"appId":"A","time":1}
```

I tried this query:

```
collection.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":{"a":"$appId"},"ttt":{"$max":"$time"}}},
{"$sort":{"_id.ttt":-1,"time":-1}}])
```

but i recieved only the last time for particular appId -> 2 results and this query change the structure of the data.
I want to keep the structure of the documents and only to group and sort them like the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { time: -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$appId",
            max: { $max: "$time" },
            items: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { max: -1 }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$items"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$items"
        }
    }
])
```

You can [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) before grouping to get the right order inside of each group. Then you can use special variable `$$ROOT` while grouping to capture whole orinal object. In the next step you can sort by `$max` value and use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get back the same amount of documents and to promote original shape to root level.

Answer (score 1):

See if the below find & sort operation works with your real data.

```
collection.find({}, {_id : 0}).sort({appId:1, time:-1})
```

If this is a huge collection and this is going to be a repetitive query, make sure to create a compound index on these two fields.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not what OP expects since your query will return following order:  `A5, A3, A1, B6, B4, B2, B1`

Comment: It will still group all the appIds (when there are multiple A5s , A3s etc), it sounded to me that OP just wants the appIds grouped somehow and then sort each group with time descending.